# How to apply a diff to source code?

Tags: git, diff

Someone sent me the output of a diff of my remote and their local.  My local is a clone of the remote with no changes.  What is the best way to apply the diff to my local without manually going through it and making each change?

```
diff --git a/path b/path
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `git apply` command will take a patch and apply it to your local directory.  There is some good discussion [here](http://ariejan.net/2009/10/26/how-to-create-and-apply-a-patch-with-git/), and of course also the [git-apply documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-apply.html).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your workflow you can use `git apply` to apply a properly formatted patch. Alternatively you could have the other party push to a shared branch `git push origin <branch>` and you could pull their branch down and merge/rebase the changes. Both of these are functionally equivalent, but the second option sports a little recordkeeping regarding your code sharing arrangement.